# Correct name of the laptop inner port / bay

Tags: lenovo-laptop, drive-bay

what is the correct description for this inner port of my laptop? What is it for?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google of the model number suggests its a thinkpad edge E330, and looking at the [service manual](https://thinkpads.com/support/hmm/hmm_pdf/e330_e335_hmm_en_0b48602_04.pdf), it suggests its slot that could either be for a PCI Express half mini card or a msata port.

Looking at the [red book](http://www.lenovo.com/psref/pdf/withdraw/ThinkPad_E330_E335_WE.pdf), and the potato quality images - most of the models of this SKU seem to have optional second PCIe port so that's certain.

I *suspect* it would work for msata too, but there's no clear indication that it will certainly work, but there's a few reports of successful upgrades

Comment: Thank you, in fact it seems to be a PCI Express / mSATA port.